# sliding sub menu like uber

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a menu like in uber help page [here](https://help.uber.com/) . How can i achieve the same menu type that is on click of the menu item the sub menu appears sliding and the other menu items disperses. how can i achieve this

```
<div class="side-memu">
  <div class="wrap">
   <ul>
      <li>Lorem
      <ul>
      <li><p>dddd</p></li>
      <li>111</li>
      <li>111</li>
      <li>111</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>


.side-memu { width:300px; background:#dfdfdf; height:200px;}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you try some responsive navigation plugins?

There are few navigation menu plugins available for your requirement which are,

[**1. slinky Navigation Menu**](https://github.com/alizahid/slinky/)

[**2. Jquery mmenu**](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/)

[**3. Multi Level push menu**](http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/)

Comment: slinky Navigation Menu - This is awesome. Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @Shl Glad it worked for you :-) . If you want you can accept my answer (If you want :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.side-memu { width:300px; background:#dfdfdf; height:200px;}
.side-memu ul ul{display:none}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="side-memu">
  <div class="wrap">
   <ul>
      <li>Lorem
      <ul>
      <li><p>dddd</p></li>
      <li>111</li>
      <li>111</li>
      <li>111</li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem
        <ul>
          <li><p>CCCC</p></li>
          <li>222</li>
          <li>222</li>
          <li>222</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
      <li>Lorem</li>
   </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.side-memu .wrap > ul > li ').click(function(){       
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle();
    });

    $(document).mouseup(function (e)
    {
        var menu = $(".wrap > ul > li > ul");

        if (!menu.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
            && menu.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container
        {
            menu.slideUp();
        }
    });
```

Here is working example: https://jsfiddle.net/npLhmhe7/

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I am looking for the one like in uber menu here https://help.uber.com/